# How can I compare two arrays of objects and change a property for those that are not equal in another arrays?

Tags: arrays

I have 2 arrays of object

```
var array1 = [{ ID:"1", IsChecked : true}, 
              { ID:"2", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"3", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"4", IsChecked : false},
              { ID:"5", IsChecked : false},
              { ID:"6", IsChecked : true}]

var array2 = [{ ID:"1", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"2", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"3", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"4", IsChecked : true}]
```

i want to compare both the arrays of objects and change a property of array1(IsChecked : true) for those object that are true(IsChecked:true) in array2 ?

This is what my expected result should look like:

```
array1 = [{ ID:"1", IsChecked : true}, 
          { ID:"2", IsChecked : true},
          { ID:"3", IsChecked : true},
          { ID:"4", IsChecked : true},
          { ID:"5", IsChecked : false},
          { ID:"6", IsChecked : false}]
```

This is what i tried:

```
var map = new Map(array2.map(({ID,IsChecked})=>[ID,IsChecked]));
                        array1.forEach(o=>{
                            if(map.get(o.ID)){
                                return;
                            }
                            o.IsChecked = false;
                        });
```

but it returns false for the array that is true in array2.
Note: Both the arrays may contain other different properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.forEach()` in conjunction with `Array.find()` method:

```js
var array1 = [{ ID:"1", IsChecked : true}, 
              { ID:"2", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"3", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"4", IsChecked : false},
              { ID:"5", IsChecked : false}]

var array2 = [{ ID:"1", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"2", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"3", IsChecked : true},
              { ID:"4", IsChecked : true}]
              
array1.forEach(function(array1Obj){
  array2Obj = array2.find(({ID})=> ID == array1Obj.ID);
  if(array2Obj && array2Obj.IsChecked){
    array1Obj.IsChecked = true;
  }
});   
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: I have other properties in both the array of objects which are different , say In array1, i have region, and in array2, i have category.. Does your code strictly checks for the equality of the properties?

Comment: I have edited my question and the requirement. Please check out.

Comment: Thank you, i just added else array1Obj.IsChecked = false; after your if condition. And it works as my requirement.